# Problema de Autorização do OAuth2 utilizando o Wamp no Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5, oauth2, php-7, wampserver

Boa noite, estou estudando API RestFull com Laravel 5.1 e deparei com um problema para solicitar uma requisição no OAuth. 
Quando executo o servidor embutido do PHP funciona normalmente

http://localhost:8001/api/pedidos

[image: Acessando o Servidor Embutido do PHP]

Quando utilizo o Wamp Server ele dar essa mensagem:

http://localhost/php/code_education/laravel/codedelivery/public/api/pedidos
[image: Utilizando o Wamp Server com PHP 7.0]

Alguém sabe o está errado? Poderia me ajudar no problema. Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tudo tranquilo até aqui. Tive um pequeno problema com o apache que não lia o parâmetro Authorization no header, mas já foi resolvido adicionando "RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]" (sem as aspas) no .htaccess.